# File with parentheses/brackets in working directory causes eval error

Tags: bash, eval, module

I encountered a strange bug today, when running a script in a directory containing a directory with parentheses in it, such as `a()`.

**Minimal working example**

I managed to reduce the bug to the following minimal working example:

Create an empty directory in `/tmp` and `cd` into it:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
```

Create a script named *foo.sh* in it containing:

```
foo() {
  somevar=1;
  case somevar in
      aha) echo "something" ;;
      *) echo "other" ;;
  esac;
};
```

Run the following command:

```
eval $(/bin/cat foo.sh)
```

There should not be any error.

Create a file with parentheses:

```
touch "a()"
```

Run the command again:

```
eval $(/bin/cat foo.sh)
```

I now get the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why does bash even care about what files are in the directory? Why do parentheses cause an error?

**System information:**

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright © 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**More detailed background and original error:**

My problem came from using a script sourcing `/usr/share/modules/init/bash` from the `environment-modules` package, as summarized here:

```
$ dpkg -l environment-modules 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                          Version                             Architecture                        Description
+++-=============================================================-===================================-===================================-================================================================================================================================
ii  environment-modules                                           4.1.1-1                             amd64                               Modular system for handling environment variables
$ source /usr/share/modules/init/bash
$ touch "a()"
$ source /usr/share/modules/init/bash
bash: eval: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: eval: line 43: ` a() _mlshdbg='' ;;'
```

Comment: It appears this has already been reported as a bug (and fixed) to the environment-modules package here: https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules/issues/220 and adding single/double quotes fixes the error. My test script could be simplified to "echo *". But why? Bash and its expansion system still confuses me... I was considering updating my question or answering, but I would really appreciate a clear explanation to what exactly is happening.

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this as a duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is neither strange nor a bug in `bash` (it does seem to be a bug in `/usr/share/modules/init/bash` though).  You are using an unquoted command substitution together with `eval`.  The string that is the result of the command substitution will, since it is unquoted, undergo word splitting and filename expansion (globbing).  The `*)` in the code matches the filename `a()`, so it is replace by this filename in the filename expansion stage.

Running your example under `set -x` highlights this:

```
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
++ cat foo.sh
+ eval 'foo()' '{' 'somevar=1;' case somevar in 'aha)' echo '"something"' ';;' 'a()' echo '"other"' ';;' 'esac;' '};'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The same thing in the `yash` shell:

```
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
+ cat foo.sh
+ eval 'foo()' '{' 'somevar=1;' case somevar in 'aha)' echo '"something"' ';;' 'a()' echo '"other"' ';;' 'esac;' '};'
eval:1: syntax error: `)' is missing
eval:1: syntax error: `esac' is missing
eval:1: syntax error: `}' is missing
```

And with `ksh93`:

```
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
+ cat foo.sh
+ eval 'foo()' '{' somevar='1;' case somevar in 'aha)' echo '"something"' ';;' 'a()' echo '"other"' ';;' 'esac;' '};'
ksh93: eval: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

And `dash`:

```
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
+ cat foo.sh
+ eval foo() { somevar=1; case somevar in aha) echo "something" ;; a() echo "other" ;; esac; };
dash: 1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Only the `zsh` would handle this as it does not perform the globbing:

```
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
+zsh:2> cat foo.sh
+zsh:2> eval 'foo()' '{' 'somevar=1;' case somevar in 'aha)' echo '"something"' ';;' '*)' echo '"other"' ';;' 'esac;' '};'
```

The correct way to handle this would be to *source* the `foo.sh` script:

```
. ./foo.sh
```

There is really no reason to use `eval "$(cat foo.sh)"` as far as I can see.

This is also a code injection vulnerability:

```
$ touch '*) echo "hello" ;; *)'
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
$ declare -f foo
foo ()
{
    somevar=1;
    case somevar in
        aha)
            echo "something"
        ;;
        *)
            echo "hello"
        ;;
        *)
            echo "other"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Another way of breaking this command easily *without* creating a specially named file, is to set the `IFS` variable to a set of characters other than the default:

```
$ IFS=';{} '
+ IFS=';{} '
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
++ cat foo.sh
+ eval 'foo()' '
' somevar=1 '
' case somevar 'in
' 'aha)' echo '"something"' '' '
' '*)' echo '"other"' '' '
' esac '
' ''
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `somevar=1'
```

This breaks it because of the word-splitting step rather than the file globbing step in the evaluation of the arguments to `eval`.  With `IFS=';{} '`, each of those characters would be used to split the text in `foo.sh` up into words (and those characters would then be removed from the string).

Not even `zsh` would be immune to this:

```
$ IFS=';{} '
+zsh:2> IFS=';{} '
$ eval $(cat foo.sh)
+zsh:3> cat foo.sh
+zsh:3> eval 'foo()' $'\n' 'somevar=1' $'\n' case somevar $'in\n' 'aha)' echo '"something"' '' $'\n' '*)' echo '"other"' '' $'\n' esac $'\n' '' ''
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

Related:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: Thanks. I learned a bit more about bash again. :) (In particular, "set -f" can fix the error too by disable filename expansion.) I also finally upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10, which fixed the environment-modules error.